# Phone gap - time tracker with progress bar

Tags: html, cordova, time, progress

I am new to phonegap, and i want to achieve time tracker progress bar i.e. 
I want to show progress bar correspondign to each time e.g. you worked for 3 hours, so in the time tracker i show progress bar corresponding to 3 hours

I searched couple of forums but i amnot able to find any solution.

Kindly help me on this.

Comment: i am not clear? Do you want to save your application starting time?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on the issue, but here is a shot in the dark:

To make a progress bar and show progress you have to have a goal (example: to show 3 hours of work in progress bar, you have to know how much work is required. So if 8 hours is required then we can show what percentage 3 hours is of 8 hours)

Here is a working example based on 3 of 8 hours of work:

```
var goal = 8;
var currentTotal = 3;

var progress = (goal / currentTotal);
document.getElementById('progress-indicator').style.width = progress + '%';
```

then in html:

```
<div id="progress" style="width: 100%;">
    <div id="progress-indicator" style="width: 0%;"></div>
</div>
```